# Create new data frame depending on the most extreme value in rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have the following data frame and I would like to create a new one that will be like the one below.

```
     ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
x1_X 0   10  4   7
x2_X 2   12  5   8
x3_X 3   1   3   5
y1_Y 4   13  6   4
y2_Y 5   14  1   9
y3_Y 2   11  1   5
y4_Y 1   1   2   3
z1_Z 1   0   0   5
z2_Z 3   6   7   7
```

New data frame

```
    ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
X   x3 x2 x2 x2
Y   y2 y2 y1 y2
Z   z2 z2 z2 z2
```

Basically the idea is the following:
For each ID I want to find which of the rownames (x1_X,x2_X,x3_X) has the most extreme value and assign this to name X since in the rownames I have subgroups.

My data frame is huge: 1700 columns and 100000 rows.

Comment: I was thinking of splitting the data frame to smaller ones (according to subgroups) and then calculate everything but i will be time and memory consuming. I can do it with Perl as i don't have a lot of experience working with R.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to split the group and subgroup labels:

```
grp <- strsplit(row.names(df), "_")
```

And if performance is an issue, I think data.table is our best choice:

```
library(data.table)
df$group <- sapply(grp, "[", 2)
subgroup <- sapply(grp, "[", 1)
dt <- data.table(df)
```

And we now have access to the single line:

```
result <- dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x)  subgroup[.I[which.max(x)]]), by=group]
```

Which  splits the data.table by the character after the underscore (`by=group`) and then, for every column of the rectangular subset (`.SD`) we get the index in the sub-rectangle (which.max), and then map it back to the whole data.table (.I), and then extract the relevant subgroup (subgroup).

The data.table package is meant to be quite efficient, though you might want to look into indexing your data.table if you're going to be querying it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried the code and i am taking the following error.
'by' or 'keyby' is supplied but not j

Comment: You must have typed in the code very quickly.  First version had a typo on the final line dt[lapply... is now dt[,lapply.... - thought I fixed it quickly, but obviously not quickly enough!

Comment: Probably... Now i am taking these warning. It seems to work only for the first group

Warning messages:

1: In which.max(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In which.max(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In which.max(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
 
 result
   group ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 subgroup
1:     X  x3  x2  x2  x2       NA
2:     Y  NA  NA  y4  NA       NA
3:     Z  NA  NA  NA  NA       NA

Comment: If you type `lapply(df, class)` and `lapply(dt, class)` you should get all numeric classes, except for _group_.   Any non-numeric columns other that _group_ will have to be excluded.  Make sure that you're not creating a column called `subgroup` - i.e. do NOT have `df$subgroup <-` in my second snippet of code

Comment: Oops mistyping..Thank you very much it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Your table:

```
df <- read.table (text= "     ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
x1_X 0   10  4   7
x2_X 2   12  5   8
x3_X 3   1   3   5
y1_Y 4   13  6   4
y2_Y 5   14  1   9
y3_Y 2   11  1   5
y4_Y 1   1   2   3
z1_Z 1   0   0   5
z2_Z 3   6   7   7", header = T)
```

Split rownames to get groups:

```
library(plyr)
df_names <- ldply(strsplit (rownames(df), "_"))
colnames(df_names) <- c ("group1", "group2")

df2 <- cbind (df, df_names)
```

Create new table:

```
df_new <- data.frame (matrix(nrow = length(unique (df2$group2)), 
                        ncol = ncol(df)))
colnames(df_new) <- colnames(df)
rownames (df_new) <- unique (df_names[["group2"]])
```

Filling new table with a loop:

```
for (i in 1:ncol (df_new)) {

  for (k in 1:nrow (df_new)) {

    col0 <- colnames (df_new)[i]
    row0 <- rownames (df_new)[k]

    sub0 <- df2 [df2$group2 == row0, c(col0, "group1")]
    df_new [k,i] <- sub0 [sub0[1]==max (sub0[1]), 2]
  }

}
```